# Is it possible to download Java updates via Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, java

Welcome as title says, is it possible to download Java updates via Google Chrome or should I have additional web browser? My operating system is Windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: Java has it's own built-in update mechanism. What is wrong with using that?

Answer (score 0):

Java is [no longer supported in Google Chrome](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml) however, you should be able to download updates.  The only problem would be where Java would not be able to test the current version installed is up to date.

The best thing to do would be to use a browser which supports Java such as Firefox, Opera or Internet Explorer as in order to use it you would need a supported browser in the first place.

Comment: Whenever, I try download updates I get error message. Access Denied

You don't have permission to access "http://sdlc-esd-stage.oracle.com/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/8u101-b13/chromeinstall-8u101.exe?" on this server.
Reference #18.5aa34b9.1474796356.94ce8e7

Comment: Have you tried IE?

Comment: Yes, in IE it works.

Comment: Java has it's own built-in update mechanism. What is wrong with using that?

Comment: I guess nothing but I disable it from autostart. Anyway, the question was mainly about possibility to manual download Java via Google Chrome but it seems it isn't possible.